# Does oracle 12c aquire automatically a table lock when it aquires a row lock?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

It says on the documentation that oracle 12c, aquires a table lock when a row lock is aquired.That is not so in sql server, it is very baffling.

```
A row lock, also called a TX lock, is a lock on a single row of a table. A transaction acquires a row lock for each row modified by one of the following statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, and SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. The row lock exists until the transaction commits or rolls back.

***When a transaction obtains a row lock for a row, the transaction also acquires a table lock for the table in which the row resides***. The table lock prevents conflicting DDL operations that would override data changes in a current transaction.
```

Can somebody elucidate this?

Comment: Please read this chapter: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT020 It's too long to explain it in the answer. In short  Oracle use DML TX locks (Data Manipulation TX Lock ) on a single row to prevent simultaneous change of the row, and at the same time Oracle places one of DDL-data manupulation (RS, RX, RSX or S) lock on a table to prevent from modifying the table itself. For example ALTER TABLE is prohibited while some transaction is holding TX lock on some row in that table, but other commands like INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT modifying others rows are still possible.

Answer (score 5):

The table lock that occurs is a *shared* lock.  There can be any number of shared locks allowed on the same table at the same time: they do not interfere with one another.

What they do do is prevent anything from acquiring an *exclusive* lock on that table: say, to change the structure of the table.